# while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) loops never execute

Tags: ipad, sqlite, while-loop

hi all
i have some problem in using sqlite in IOS. i have select  data from database, and then i want to save that data in a variable. But when i use `while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)` loop, the code never execute.

here is my code :

```
-(void)retrieveProjectNameFromDb:(NSString *)segmenId{
NSString *query;
NSString *nameProjectStr; 

NSString *dbPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"database" ofType:@"sqlite"];
if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) != SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlite3_close(db);
    NSAssert(0, @"Database failed to open.");

}else {
    query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT remote_projectname, remote_base_uri FROM REMOTE_SETTING WHERE remote_settingid = '%@' ORDER BY remote_projectname", segmenId];
    NSLog(@"query : %@", query);
}

sqlite3_stmt *statement;


if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)==SQLITE_OK){

    NSLog(@"sqlite row : %d", SQLITE_ROW);
    NSLog(@"sqlite 3 : %d", sqlite3_step(statement));

    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {


        char *nameProject = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
        if (nameProject == nil) {
            NSLog(@"UNNAMED");
        }else {
            NSLog(@"else");

            nameProjectStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:nameProject];
        }

        projectName.text = nameProjectStr;
        nameProject = nil;  
    }

    NSLog(@"project name : %@", projectName.text);


    sqlite3_close(db);

}
```

}

when i nslog the value, sqlite3_step(statement) always show 101 and sqlite_row always show 100. Why it can happen??
can somebody help me, please?

thank you

Regards

-risma-

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you mentioned sqlite3_step(statement) always show 101 which means sqlite3_step has finished executions hence it means your sql query is not returning any rows from database. I would recommend you to first check in database if any record exists in table REMOTE_SETTING for remote_settingid which you are referring.

For your reference I took following constant snippet from sqlite.org

```
#define SQLITE_DONE        101  /* sqlite_step() has finished executing */
```

Comment: @sandy: I have record in my database still  sqlite3_step(statement) always show 101 and some time both equal means sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW here 100=100.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the NSLog entry in which you are having sqlite3_step(). Since you have your NSLog statement executing sqlite3_step(), the record is already stepped through here. Hence, your while loop won't execute as there are no more rows to step through.
I think this will surely help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

From your description of the logging output I would guess that your query is returning an empty row set.  However I can see two other problems here:

1. You discard the result of your first call to `sqlite3_step`, because you log it then immediately call `sqlite3_step` again.  That means you will miss the first row.
2. You probably should not be closing the database after a single query.  You should finalize the statement after the query, but only close the database when your app shuts down.

Try:

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)==SQLITE_OK){

    NSLog(@"sqlite row : %d", SQLITE_ROW);
    int stepResult = sqlite3_step(statement);
    NSLog(@"sqlite 3 : %d", stepResult);

    while (stepResult == SQLITE_ROW) {


        char *nameProject = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
        if (nameProject == nil) {
            NSLog(@"UNNAMED");
        }else {
            NSLog(@"else");

            nameProjectStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:nameProject];
        }

        projectName.text = nameProjectStr;
        nameProject = nil;  
        stepResult = sqlite3_step(statement);
    }

    NSLog(@"project name : %@", projectName.text);

    sqlite3_finalize(&statement);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this..

```
sqlite3 *database1;
    NSString *sqlStatement1 = @"";
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database1) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        sqlStatement1 = [NSString stringWithString:@"SELECT uniqueid from shortlisted"];
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement1;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database1, [sqlStatement1 cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], -1, &compiledStatement1, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
        {
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement1) == SQLITE_ROW) 
            {
                 NSString * str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];

            }   
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement1);
        sqlite3_close(database1);


    }
```

Also close database instance whenever you open them.. if you are not closing an instance then that can cause issues..

Sorry I am pasting this from my project.. but actually I am in a bit hurry... I'll modify this answer when I reach home...